# How to prove that $\tan(x)=\sin(x)+1$ has only one solution in $(−\pi/2,\pi/2)$ using the Rolle's theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> How to prove that $\tan(x)=\sin(x)+1$ has only one solution in $(−\pi/2,\pi/2)$ using the Rolle's theorem?

I denoted the function $-f(x) = \tan(x)- \sin(x)- 1,$ and showed by I.V.T. that there exists a $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

I also know the derivative $f'(x)= 1/\cos(x)^2 - \cos(x)$.

Also, I know that $f'(t) = 0$ by Rolle's theorem, but from here I got stuck.

Comment: You know that $f'(t)=0$ by Rolle's Theorem? What do you mean? When does that happen?

Comment: Please use MathJax when you post on this forum. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In which segment, did you apply IVT.

Comment: I understand when someone doesn't how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write the questions, but you can't even write $\pi/2$ instead of $\pi 2$? Or did you just copy-paste and didn't read what you wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ J=(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2)$ and $ f(x)=\tan(x)-\sin(x)-1$.

$ f $ is differentiable at $  J $ and
For any $ x\in J$,

$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$
$$=\frac{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))}{\cos^2(x)}\ge 0$$

and
$$f'(x)=0\iff x=0$$

Thus $ f $ is strictly increasing at $ J $.

On the other hand
$$f(0)=-1<0\text{ and } \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}^-}f(x)=+\infty$$

therefore, $$\exists b\in(0,\frac \pi 2)\; : f(b)>0$$

By IVT, at $ [0,b] $,
$$\exists c\in (0,b) \;:\; f(c)=0$$

Assuming that there are two roots
$ c_1$ and $ c_2 \in (0,b) $ then by Rolle's Theorem

$$\exists a\in(c_1,c_2) \;:\; f'(a)=0$$

but
$$\forall x\in (0,b) \;\;f'(x)>0$$

since $\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)+1 =(\cos(x)+\frac 12)^2+\frac 34>0$ .

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer! 
Sadly we haven't learned yet discriminates, is there another way to end the proof?

Comment: @MorLevy For any real $t$, $t^2 + t + 1 = (t+1/2)^2 -1/4 + 1 > 0$.

Answer (score -1):

for all $x, \frac 1{\cos^2 x} \ge 1$ and $\cos x \le 1$

When $x = 0, f'(x) = 0$ otherwise $f'(x)$ is always positive.

This is enough to show that $f(x)$ is monotonic in the interval, and can have at most 1 zero.